# how to find that a word in a column is present in another column consisting a whole sentence

Tags: r, string

I am looking forward for a R solution that can check whether a word (in column 1) is present in a sentence (column 2) of a data frame or not. If the word is present in the sentence, than it should return 1 (TRUE) or else 0 (FALSE).
[image: This is how my DF looks] and [image: This is how it should look like]

I would be highly thankful for any sort of help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find that a word/words in a column is present in another column consisting a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461707/how-to-find-that-a-word-words-in-a-column-is-present-in-another-column-consistin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grepl()`:

```
df$t <- apply(df, 1, function(x) grepl(x[1], x[2]))
df
      substring                      string     t
1         phone this is my new mobile phone  TRUE
2        phones      Yes, I have two phones  TRUE
3 telephonessss            my old telephone FALSE
4  telephone234                   telephone FALSE
```

Note that this solution uses the `apply()` function in row mode.  Conceptually we want to check whether each substring is contained in the string, for each row of the data frame.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Using `apply` on a dataframe is a mess. You could just do `with(df, mapply(grepl, substring, string))`. And this is a dupe btw.

Comment: @DavidArenburg When you say "mess" are you worried about performance, the code, or both?

Comment: All of these + side effects. `apply` is only good for matrices. It messes up and behaves unexpectedly for anything else (compare `apply(iris, 2, class)` with `str(iris)`, for instance). Not to mention performance and nasty code.

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for the solution. But still I have a little problem as my substring is also a string (has more than one word), and due to that the apply() and grepl() is not working. For Instance, in Substring I have "my new phone" and in String I have "this is my new mobile phone". Then in that case I would get a false in t column.

Comment: @Faraz I would recommend that you ask a new question.  This new requirement is a large departure from your original requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `stri_detect_fixed` from `stringi` package

So first I've created small data frame from two vectors

```
substring <- c("phone", "phones", "telephonesss")
string <- c("this is my new mobile phone", "Yes, I have two phones","my old telephone")
df <- data.frame(substring, string)
```

Then I've created new column in data frame named "t" containing values TRUE or FALSE

```
 df$t <- stri_detect_fixed(df$string, df$subatring)
```

And the output

```
> df
     substring                      string t
1        phone this is my new mobile phone  TRUE
2       phones      Yes, I have two phones  TRUE
3 telephonesss            my old telephone FALSE
```

Comment: Hi Miha. Thanks for the solution. But still I have a little problem as my substring is also a string (has more than one word), and due to that the stri_detect_fixed command is not working well. For Instance, in Substring I have "my new phone" and in String I have "this is my new mobile phone". Then in that case I would get a false in t column.