# Searching keywords on multiple columns

Tags: r, grepl, mapply

I have a dataset which has search words and other attributes like title, short description and product description. I want to loopup "Search" words in multiple columns and want to get results as "Tru or False" for each and every column

With the great solution mentioned on this page "[How to find that a word/words in a column is present in another column consisting a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461707/how-to-find-that-a-word-words-in-a-column-is-present-in-another-column-consistin/45462050#45462050)", I figured out the way to get results for one column,but since I am very new to R(And coding), I am unable to figure out how to get the results on multiple columns without writing the same code again and again for every column.

```
df<-data.frame(search, short_description, product_description)

df[, "lookup"] <- gsub(" ", "|", df[,("search")])
df[,"t"] <- mapply(grepl, df[,"lookup"], df[, "short_description"])
```

search values:

```
row1: aps mobile electronics specialty-aps electronics-intl-ship warehouse-deals
row2: maschine phone gadgets iphone

Short description

row1: mobile is good


row2: everyone uses iphone

product_description

row1: (blank)



row2: mobiles are required
```

"structure(list(search = structure(1:2, .Label = c("aps mobile electronics specialty-aps electronics-intl-ship warehouse-deals", 
"maschine phone gadgets iphone"), class = "factor"), short_description = structure(2:1, .Label = c("everyone use iphone", 
"mobile is good"), class = "factor"), product_description = structure(1:2, .Label = c("", 
"mobiles are required"), class = "factor"), lookup = c("aps|mobile|electronics|specialty-aps|electronics-intl-ship|warehouse-deals", 
"maschine|phone|gadgets|iphone"), t = c(TRUE, TRUE)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")"

Expected Output "t1" for every attribute:
[search keyword and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/res3T.png)

> 1) I want to get the "t" column to show the search results for every column. (and not the combined result).

Can I simply select the column numbers in my code and get this data?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post your data in a reproducible format using `dput(head(YOUR_DATA))` and posting the results.  Also, post an example of what you want your end product to look like.

Comment: Thanks Ben, Have edited it!

Comment: Hi  @BenG will it be possible for you to help with the solution?