# How to find how many time a word from one column is present in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, gsub, grepl

I am looking for a solution in R to find how many time a word from a column/columns is present in another column of a data frame.

I have a DF with 4 columns (page, text, wildanimals and animals).

```
df <- tibble::tibble(page=c(12,6,9,18,2),
                 text=c("Dogs are related to wolves, but dogs are friendly",
                        "I love pets",
                        "I like goat and deer. Deer and goat",
                        "Zebra have stripes on their body",
                        "Lizards are Crocodiles have tails"
                        ))
wildanimals <- c("wolves", "tiger", "deer", "zebra", "crocodile")
animals <- c("dogs", "cats", "goat", "horse", "lizard")

cbind(df,animals, wildanimals)
```

I want to check if the words in column animals and wildanimals are present in column text and how many times. Something like this:

```
frequency <- c("3","0","4", "1", "2")
cbind(df,animals, wildanimals,frequency)
```

I have asked similar question here: [Link to the Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458787/how-to-find-that-a-word-in-a-column-is-present-in-another-column-consisting-a-wh), but it only tells if the word is present or not.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `str_count` to count the words that are in 'animals', 'wildanimals' can add (`+`) them together

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
   mutate(frequency = str_count(text, coll(animals, ignore_case = TRUE)) + 
                      str_count(text, coll(wildanimals, ignore_case = TRUE)))
df1
#  page                                              text animals wildanimals frequency
#1   12 Dogs are related to wolves, but dogs are friendly    dogs      wolves         3
#2    6                                       I love pets    cats       tiger         0
#3    9               I like goat and deer. Deer and goat    goat        deer         4
#4   18                  Zebra have stripes on their body   horse       zebra         1
#5    2                 Lizards are Crocodiles have tails  lizard   crocodile         2
```

---

Or in a compact way by `paste`ing the 'animals', 'wildanimals' column into a single one with `sep` as `|` and wrap with `regex` instead of `coll` in `str_count`

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
   mutate(frequency = str_count(text, 
      regex(str_c(animals, wildanimals, sep="|"), ignore_case = TRUE)))
df1
#   page                                              text animals wildanimals frequency
#1   12 Dogs are related to wolves, but dogs are friendly    dogs      wolves         3
#2    6                                       I love pets    cats       tiger         0
#3    9               I like goat and deer. Deer and goat    goat        deer         4
#4   18                  Zebra have stripes on their body   horse       zebra         1
#5    2                 Lizards are Crocodiles have tails  lizard   crocodile         2
```

NOTE: `%>%` doesn't create the column in place, so we need to reassign (`<-`) it to the original object.  If we want to create the column in place in the original object 'df1', use the `magrittr` operator (`%<>%`)

Comment: Could also use `glue::glue()`: `df %>% mutate(frequency = str_count(tolower(text), glue("{animals}|{wildanimals}")))`

Comment: @andrew_reece Looks good to me.  Could you also post that as a solution.  Thanks

Comment: Sure - it seemed close enough to you that I thought maybe a comment was more appropriate.  But I'll add as a separate solution now.

Comment: @akrun Thanks for the solution. Can you also please provide a way how I can save it as a data frame. I don't have the "frequency" column in my data frame "df".

Comment: @Fraxxx  If you want  column only as a separate data.frame.  just change the `mutate` to `transmute`i.e. `df2 <- df1 %>% transmute(frequency = str_count(text, 
      regex(str_c(animals, wildanimals, sep="|"), ignore_case = TRUE)))`

Comment: @akrun No, When I run your solution, the data frame "df" doesn't have the frequency column. I need the data frame with all columns including frequency.

Comment: @Fraxxx  Just do `df1 <- df1 %>%  mutate(frequency = str_count(text, coll(animals, ignore_case = TRUE)) + 
                      str_count(text, coll(wildanimals, ignore_case = TRUE)))`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to use `str_count` is by merging `animals` and `wildanimals` with  [`glue::glue()`](https://github.com/tidyverse/glue). Then match against the lowercase version of `text`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(frequency = str_count(tolower(text), glue("{animals}|{wildanimals}")))
```